# Boot error: Can't install Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 on Fujitsu Siemens notebook (Amilo SI3655) - No operating system found

Tags: boot, system-installation, 16.04

i just installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and can't boot anymore. Neither the default installation, nor manual partitioning worked.

My last configuration can be seen [here](http://paste2.org/5p3P5LDh).

As you can see I already tried Boot-Repair, but it made no difference.

I exchanged the HDD by a SSD 2 years ago. Installing Ubuntu 14.04 worked. Now I wanted to make a fresh install with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching boot mode in your BIOS?

I don't know if your computer is currently set to Legacy or UEFI, but I presume it is currently set to legacy. Change it to UEFI and see what happens.

*Cheers*

Comment: There is no such option in the bios, the notebook is 7 years old i think and i doubt there is an update.

Comment: I doubt Gnome is going to run well on 7 year old hardware. I suggest using something like Ubuntu MATE: https://ubuntu-mate.org/

Answer (score 0):

Soo, well... in the third try i did the following partitioning:

1) primary [boot] - ext4 - 2GB - /boot
2) logical - swap - 4GB
3) logical - ext4 - REST-OF-SPACE - /

Installed and works. I made some bootrepair runs in between and tried to fix MBR, etc - nothing worked. So i think the solution could be (i may blame myself here because i do NOT have the knowhow to tell for sure), that the first partition needs to have the boot flag and the boot mount on that specific BIOS version.